# Pandas groupby mean of only positive values

Tags: python, pandas

How to get mean of only positive values after groupby in pandas?

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

flights = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Datasets/blob/master/nycflights13.csv?raw=true')
print(flights.shape)
print(flights.iloc[:2,:4])
print()

not_cancelled = flights.dropna(subset=['dep_delay','arr_delay'])

df = (not_cancelled.groupby(['year','month','day'])['arr_delay']
      .mean().reset_index()
     )

df['avg_delay2'] = df[df.arr_delay>0]['arr_delay'].mean()

print(df.head())
```

This gives all avg_delay2 values as 16.66.

(336776, 19)
   year  month  day  dep_time
0  2013      1    1     517.0
1  2013      1    1     533.0

year  month  day  arr_delay  avg_delay2
0  2013      1    1  12.651023   16.665681
1  2013      1    2  12.692888   16.665681
2  2013      1    3   5.733333   16.665681
3  2013      1    4  -1.932819   16.665681
4  2013      1    5  -1.525802   16.665681

Which is WRONG.

```
# sanity check
a = not_cancelled.query(""" year==2013 & month ==1 & day ==1 """)['arr_delay']
a = a[a>0]
a.mean() # 32.48156182212581
```

When I do the same thing in R:

```
library(nycflights13)

not_cancelled = flights %>% 
    filter( !is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay))

df = not_cancelled  %>%  
    group_by(year,month,day) %>%  
    summarize(
        # average delay
        avg_delay1 = mean(arr_delay),
        # average positive delay
        avg_delay2 = mean(arr_delay[arr_delay>0]))

head(df)
```

It gives correct output for avg_delay2.

year    month   day avg_delay1  avg_delay2
2013    1   1   12.651023   32.48156
2013    1   2   12.692888   32.02991
2013    1   3   5.733333    27.66087
2013    1   4   -1.932819   28.30976
2013    1   5   -1.525802   22.55882
2013    1   6   4.236429    24.37270

How to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would filter the positive before `groupby`

```
df = (not_cancelled[not_cancelled.arr_delay >0].groupby(['year','month','day'])['arr_delay']
      .mean().reset_index()
     )
df.head()
```

because, as in your code, `df` is an separate dataframe **after** the `groupby` operation has completed, and

```
df['avg_delay2'] = df[df.arr_delay>0]['arr_delay'].mean()
```

assign the same value to `df['avg_delay2']`

Edit: Similar to R, you can do both in one shot using `agg`:

```
def mean_pos(x):
    return x[x>0].mean()

df = (not_cancelled.groupby(['year','month','day'])['arr_delay']
      .agg({'arr_delay': 'mean', 'arr_delay_2': mean_pos})
     )
df.head()
```

Comment: I did a similar thing, it took me a while to do the thing in python, while it was just one more line in R. I was always under the WRONG impression that `pandas` is nearly useful as `dplyr`. I am wrong.

Comment: @astro123 see my updated answer for a concise version.

Comment: We may not use dictionary in future versions of pandas. It gives Deprecation warning in pandas 23.

Comment: I didn't realize that. In that case, just do `.agg(['mean', mean_pos])`, the two new columns would be `['mean', 'mean_pos']` and you can rename them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Note that from pandas 23, using dictionary in gropby agg is deprecated and will be removed in future, so we can not use that method.

## Warning

```
df = (not_cancelled.groupby(['year','month','day'])['arr_delay']
      .agg({'arr_delay': 'mean', 'arr_delay_2': mean_pos})
     )

FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```

So, I to tackle that problem in this specific case, I came up with another idea.

Create a new column making all non-positive values nans, then do the usual groupby.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# read data
flights = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Datasets/blob/master/nycflights13.csv?raw=true')

# select flights that are not cancelled
df = flights.dropna(subset=['dep_delay','arr_delay'])

# create new column to fill non-positive with nans
df['arr_delay_pos'] = df['arr_delay']
df.loc[df.arr_delay_pos <= 0,'arr_delay_pos'] = np.nan
df.groupby(['year','month','day'])[['arr_delay','arr_delay_pos']].mean().reset_index().head()
```

It gives:

```
   year  month  day  arr_delay  arr_delay_positive
0  2013      1    1  12.651023           32.481562
1  2013      1    2  12.692888           32.029907
2  2013      1    3   5.733333           27.660870
3  2013      1    4  -1.932819           28.309764
4  2013      1    5  -1.525802           22.558824
```

## Sanity check

```
# sanity check
a = not_cancelled.query(""" year==2013 & month ==1 & day ==1 """)['arr_delay']
a = a[a>0]
a.mean() # 32.48156182212581
```